# Invalid credentials with SASL_PLAINTEXT mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256 - InvalidACL for /config/users/admin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I am using `kafka_2.3.0`, `Ubuntu 16.04`

Below are the configurations for Kafka broker and the zookeeper nodes. Currently i am testing this on single machine so the IP shall remain same all over and port shall differ.

## kafka-broker 1 configuration.

```
broker.id=1
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9092
log.dirs=/home/emgda/data/kafka/1/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.172:2181,192.168.1.172:2182,192.168.1.172:2183
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret";
```

## kafka-broker 2 configuration.

```
broker.id=2
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9093
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9093
log.dirs=/home/emgda/data/kafka/2/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.172:2181,192.168.1.172:2182,192.168.1.172:2183
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret";
```

## kafka-broker 3 configuration.

```
broker.id=3
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9094
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.172:9094
log.dirs=/home/emgda/data/kafka/3/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.172:2181,192.168.1.172:2182,192.168.1.172:2183
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret";
```

## kafka_jass.config

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="super"
   password="adminsecret";
};
```

## zookeeper_jass.conf

```
Server {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_super="adminsecret";
};
```

## Zookeeper-node 1 configuration

```
dataDir=/home/emgda/data/zookeeper/1/
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2666:3666
server.2=localhost:2667:3667
server.3=localhost:2668:3668
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

## Zookeeper-node 2 configuration

```
dataDir=/home/emgda/data/zookeeper/2/
clientPort=2182
server.1=localhost:2666:3666
server.2=localhost:2667:3667
server.3=localhost:2668:3668
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

## Zookeeper-node 3 configuration

```
dataDir=/home/emgda/data/zookeeper/3/
clientPort=2183
server.1=localhost:2666:3666
server.2=localhost:2667:3667
server.3=localhost:2668:3668
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

Zookeeper nodes in cluster start properly and the kafka is also able to authenticate to zookeeper as below zookeeper logs will help understand what heppens when first kafka broker comes up,

```
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,465] INFO Accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.172:42362 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,480] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.1.172:42362 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,487] INFO Established session 0x10000d285210003 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /192.168.1.172:42362 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,529] INFO Successfully authenticated client: authenticationID=super;  authorizationID=super. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,529] INFO Setting authorizedID: super (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2019-12-30 13:35:29,530] INFO adding SASL authorization for authorizationID: super (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-12-30 13:36:54,999] INFO Closed socket connection for client /192.168.1.172:42362 which had sessionid 0x10000d285210003 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

## Error while starting first Kafka broker as below,

```
[2019-12-30 13:35:58,417] ERROR [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (192.168.1.172/192.168.1.172:9092) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-30 13:35:58,421] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /192.168.1.172 (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

While I am trying to create a Kakfa-broker user using below command, I get below error

```
emgda@ubuntu:~/softwares/kafka_2.12-2.3.0$ ./bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper 192.168.1.172:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=admin-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin
Error while executing config command with args '--zookeeper 192.168.1.172:2181 --alter --add-config SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=admin-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin-secret] --entity-type users --entity-name admin'
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /config/users/admin
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:124)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:560)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1610)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createOrSet$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:357)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.setOrCreateEntityConfigs(KafkaZkClient.scala:367)
        at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.changeEntityConfig(AdminZkClient.scala:378)
        at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.changeUserOrUserClientIdConfig(AdminZkClient.scala:312)
        at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.changeConfigs(AdminZkClient.scala:276)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:153)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processCommandWithZk(ConfigCommand.scala:104)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:80)
        at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

## Question:

What am I missing so that kafka-broker authenticates in a proper way?

Comment: Looks like you need to do something like this `kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter
      --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=foo]'
      --entity-type users --entity-name PRINC` ... Or just use the Ansible scripts from Confluent to set this up for yourself. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible/blob/5.3.1-post/roles/confluent.kafka_broker/tasks/main.yml#L95-L99

Comment: @cricket_007: updated my question with more details at the end.

Comment: I think you can remove `SCRAM-SHA-512` configs from that command

Comment: Maybe see if you missed something here https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_scram.html

Comment: @cricket_007: I removed `SCRAM-SHA-512`, still same error